# Cross Apply remove NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to remove the row with NULL values on Crit_Value column. Appreciate your help.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GP.PRIORITY_CD,  CODE_Val
    FROM   TCRITERIA_GROUP_PS GP


   CROSS APPLY ( SELECT PV.CODE + ',' 
                     FROM   TCRITERIA_GROUP_PS_VALUE GPV
    --JOIN TCRITERIA_GROUP_PS GP ON GP.CRITERIA_GROUP_PS_ID = GPV.CRITERIA_GROUP_PS_ID
    JOIN TCRITERIA_PS_VALUE PV ON PV.CRITERIA_PS_VALUE_ID = GPV.CRITERIA_PS_VALUE_ID
    JOIN TCRITERIA_PS CP ON PV.CRITERIA_PS_ID = CP.CRITERIA_PS_ID
    WHERE
    PV.PARTNER_ID = 'JETSTAR'
    AND GP.PARTNER_SYS_ID = 'JETSTAR1'
    AND GP.ISO_CNTRY_CD = 'AU'
    AND GP.CRITERIA_GROUP_PS_ID = GPV.CRITERIA_GROUP_PS_ID
    FOR XML PATH('') )  D ( CODE_Val )
```

RESULTSET of the Query:

```
PRIORITY_CD    CODE_Val
-------------------------
1              NULL
1              AU,AU,AUD,OW,0_1999,
2              NULL
2              AU,AU,AUD,OW,2000_99999,
3              NULL
3              AU,AU,AUD,RT,0_1999,
4              NULL
4              AU,AU,AUD,RT,2000_99999,
5              NULL
5              AU,ALL_EX,AUD,OW,
```

Comment: Here is the Resultset:

PRIORITY_CD CODE_Val

1 NULL

1 AU,AU,AUD,OW,0_1999,

2 NULL

2 AU,AU,AUD,OW,2000_99999,

Comment: there is an icon that looks lie this `{}` in the toolbar above the edit area, use that to format "code", and please do NOT use comments for results

Comment: MySQL <> MS SQL

Comment: Thanks for the advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the correlation between the main table and the subquery, or add a where clause to filter out the NULLs

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  GP.PRIORITY_CD
, D.CODE_Val
FROM TCRITERIA_GROUP_PS GP
CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT
        PV.CODE + ','
      FROM TCRITERIA_GROUP_PS_VALUE GPV
      JOIN TCRITERIA_PS_VALUE PV ON PV.CRITERIA_PS_VALUE_ID = GPV.CRITERIA_PS_VALUE_ID
      JOIN TCRITERIA_PS CP ON PV.CRITERIA_PS_ID = CP.CRITERIA_PS_ID
      WHERE PV.PARTNER_ID = 'JETSTAR'
      AND GP.PARTNER_SYS_ID = 'JETSTAR1'
      AND GP.ISO_CNTRY_CD = 'AU'
      AND GP.PRIORITY_CD = GPV.CRITERIA_GROUP_PS_ID -- changed
      FOR xml PATH ('')
    ) D (CODE_Val)
-- WHERE D.CODE_Val IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: if this is your first question here you may not know that you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer. This alerts others that the question has been solved hence saving time, and/or letting other also searching for similar answers